# How to install Xcode 4.0 and iOS SDK 5.0 with Xcode 3.2.6 already installed

Tags: ios4, xcode4.2, xcode3.2

I am trying to install Xcode 4 on my mac which already has Xcode 3.2.6 installed.

I searched for this and I found that I  need to change the location for the directory  to install Xcode, however in my case my machine has only one hard drive partition  and when I try to install it on different directory there is no option available other than `Developer` (the default).

So I want the exact procedure to install Xcode 4 alongside Xcode 3.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thnx andrea but i found solution that there is option while installing xcode4  location to install it and like "other> browse for directory u wish to install in "  click continue this folder should be different than default developer.

Answer (score 0):

I previously removed the old version with all SDK (iOS 3 and 4) and, after that, installed the new version.

to remove use:

/Developer/Library/uninstall-devtools